# EF select statement

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a  model class as below

```
 public class Employee()
 {
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public string Age  {get; set;}
   ..
   ..
 }
```

suppose if I am updating the age of employee I will do by follwing linq

```
 DbContext db = new DbContext();
 Employee employee = dc.Emplyees.where(x=>x.id==id).FirstorDefault();
 employee.Age ="22";
 db.SaveChanges();
```

My Question is for Updating the Age i need to fetch all columns is there any Way by which i can fetch only ID and age and update Age;

Thanks

Comment: You could do that with a stored procedure, but what issue are you running into? You can shorten that logic up a bit: var employee = dc.Emplyees.Find(id);

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not out of the box, no. The way Entity Framework works is such that it tracks full objects. You need the full object in order to make a change to that object and update it. Otherwise, Entity Framework will just null all the other properties out because it will interpret that you meant to clear there values by not sending anything for them.

You can, however, work with the database directly, and either issue an UPDATE or call are stored procedure that will do the update, manually. You can do this within your context, if you like, and then merely call the method from your controller, so all the database stuff is still in the same place. Within the context, the `Database` instance property has everything you need to execute SQL directly.

Answer (score 1):

First, you select only the age

```
var employee = db.Employees.Where(x => x.Id == id).Select(x => new Employee{ Id = x.Id, Age = x.Age}).FirstOrDefault();
```

By doing this, you will just retrieve the age and the id from the database.

For the update, you can do it like this

```
var employee = new Employee{Id = id, Name = "My new Name", Age = 25};
db.Employees.Attach(employee);
db.Entry(employee).Property(x => x.Name).IsModified = true;
db.Entry(employee).Property(x => x.Age).IsModified = true;
db.SaveChanges();
```